# Validate object based on the owner its parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, model, has-many-through

I have a `has_many through` association setup between my artist and album models. To add to this an album `has_many` tracks. The tracks also have a `has_many through` association between artists (i.e. *featured artist*) where the `Feature` model serves as the join table.

I want to prevent the album artist(s) from being a *featured artist* on a track. So for instance:

```
album = Album.find_by(name: "Justified")
track = Album.track.first
artist = Artist.find_by(name: "Justin Timberlake")

track.featured_artists << artist 

# ^^ Should raise error since Justin Timberlake is the album's artist
```

**Model Setup**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :artists, through: :album_artists
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album

  has_many :features
  has_many :featured_artists, through: :features, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: "artist_id"
end

class AlbumArtist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :artist

  validates_uniqueness_of :artist_id, scope: :album_id
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :featured_artist, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: "artist_id"
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, through: :album_artists

  has_many :features
  has_many :tracks, through: :features
end
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using one of the out-of-the-box validation methods? If not how would I go about in creating a custom validator without writing a ridiculously long lookup chain to the album's owner, assuming the validator is in the `Feature` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test that the intersection (&) of the two artists array is empty.

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album

  has_many :features
  has_many :featured_artists, through: :features, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: "artist_id"

  validate :featured_artists_cannot_include_album_artists

  def featured_artists_cannot_include_album_artists
    if (album.artists & featured_artists).present?
      errors.add(:featured_artists, "can't include album artists")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Unless I'm approaching the build wrong it still seems to be adding the album artist. Here's what I'm doing in the console: `track.featured_artists << artist`

Comment: It won't prevent you from adding the artist... nothing can do that except monkey patching `<<` ... but it'll make the track record fail validation and you won't be able to save it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I'm finding out more everyday how difficult the shovel method can be...